# Move Items per rule after they are one day old

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, macros, rules, exchange-2010

I'm not even sure if this is possible with Outlook's current rule set but I thought I'd ask.

I'd like emails that meet certain characteristics to automatically be moved from my inbox after they are a day old.

I get a lot of notification emails that I end up having to remove the next day manually since I get new ones to replace them each day.

So a rule would be like:

> If the email is from report@example.com and older then 1 day move to already read folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to make Outlook run rules other than upon receipt or sending.  May be possible with VBA, but I've never done Outlook automation so I can't help you there.

However, you could make a rule to move the alerts to a separate folder upon arrival, then set the auto-archive option on that folder to remove when older than one day.  This would not leave the new alerts in your inbox directly, but it would keep them organized and show you only the new ones in the alerts folder.

Comment: I thought about that, but I use my inbox much as a task list as well so a second box hurts that and makes it more difficult to see what I have!

Comment: Just ended up making a macro that triggers an unchecked rule; Sub moveMessages()
Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("offlineMove").Execute
End Sub
It works I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The way outlook processes rules is to check as the item arrives in the inbox. Otherwise you'd have a performance problem as outlook searches through potentially thousands of old messages to see when some message reaches some new timing criteria.

What you might be able to do is write the rule to trigger off of the replacement message, so when the new message arrives it knows to replace the old one. But I doubt that's likely to work either.